# Ruby Telegram Bot, passing value to CallbackQuery?

Tags: ruby, telegram

I have a Telegram Bot which updates scores for a set of teams.

Teams are dynamic in size.

```
def collection_keyboard(identity)
  ip_addr = "127.0.0.1:27017"
  client = Mongo::Client.new([ip_addr], :database => "camp")

  kb = []
  client[:inventory].find({"owner": identity}, projection: {"_id": 0, "name": 1}).each do |doc|
    kb << Telegram::Bot::Types::InlineKeyboardButton.new(text: doc.to_s , callback_data: ??) //What do i put as the callback data?
  end
  markup = Telegram::Bot::Types::InlineKeyboardMarkup.new(inline_keyboard: kb)
  return markup
end
```

The above method queries the db and creates an inline keyboard, allowing users to choose which teams score to increment.

```
Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot|
  bot.listen do |message|
    case message
    when Telegram::Bot::Types::CallbackQuery
      if message.data == ?? //What do i check here?

      end
    end
```

A second inlinekeyboard will be created once the first CallbackQuery has been returned. This keyboard will allow a user to choose how many points to give e.g. 10, 20, 30.

However, since the group size vary, how do I pass the value of the Inline Keyboard which he user has clicked so that I can add points to that particular team? Since the group is dynamic, I cannot capture all possible callback return value with the regular switch statement?

For example, if a user clicks `Yellow`, how can I pass this value to the next InlineKeyboard such that the user can add `10` points to them?